# Array values update

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1``
        [1] => 2``
        [2] => 3``
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4``
        [1] => 5``
        [2] => 6``
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 7``
        [2] => 
    )
)
```

I want the result like this below,

```
$remaining_value =  Array
(
    [0] => 1`` 4``, 
    [1] => 2`` 5`` 7``,
    [2] => 3`` 6``,
)
```

How to do this in an single loop.. Plz help me..

Comment: Will the second dimension of arrays always be the same size? For instance, in your above example, each array in the second dimension is of the same size, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lower-level arrays will always have the same number of elements then you can do something like this:

```
$subArrayCount = count( $inputArray );
$outputArray = array();
$firstSubArray = reset( $inputArray );
foreach( $firstSubArray as $key => $value )
{
    $outputArray[$key] = $value;
    for( $innerLoop = 1; $innerLoop < $subArrayCount; $innerLoop++ )
    {
        $outputArray[$key].= $inputArray[$innerLoop][$key];
    }
}

var_dump( $outputArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$remaining_value=array();
foreach($array as $loopv1){
foreach($loopv1 as $key2 => $loopv2){
if(empty($remaining_value[$key2]))$remaining_value[$key2]=$loopv2; else $remaining_value[$key2].=" ".$loopv2;
}
}
?>
```